# CSS: input['submit'] inconsistent heights

Tags: html, css, undefined-behavior

So today i was messing around with some inputs. I had 2 inputs; 1 text field, 1 submit button. 
I set the heights to be identical on them both, but, for some bizarre reason they weren't. I tried resetting padding, max/min height. To no avail. In the end i settled for identical font-size and paddings to achieve equal heights. What is the reasoning behind this, can anyone explain the logic, is this intentional?

JSFiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/FecEe/

**HTML**

```
<p>See how the heights are set to be the same, but yet, they are displated differently?</p>
<input class="sample1" type="text" name="email" placeholder="john@example.com">
<input class="sample1" type="submit" name="post" value="Enter">

<br><br>

<p>See how the height isn't set explicitly but the inherited height from the text and padding make the height the same?</p>                            
<input class="sample2" type="text" name="email" placeholder="john@example.com">
<input class="sample2" type="submit" name="post" value="Enter">
```

**CSS:**

```
.sample1{
    height: 50px; /* ...? */
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 2em;
    outline:none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.sample2{ 
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 2em;
    outline:none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: `* { box-sizing: border-box }`: http://jsfiddle.net/FecEe/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for an explanation, not a solution, look at the jsfiddle - i already have a solution.

Comment: Also box-sizing is IE8+ :/

Comment: you can read bout it here http://learnlayout.com/box-sizing.html

Comment: I did. The `<input>` element has both a border and padding, which is added onto the height that you want: `50px + 2 * 10px + 2 * 1px = 72px`, which is exactly the computed height. Using `box-sizing: content-box;` makes the resulting size more "intuitive". I'm sure IE7 users are used to seeing websites all messed up, so I don't think they'll notice anything out of place even if you do use it.

Comment: Okay thanks, why isn't this sorted in CSS directly?

Comment: Also, my point was that they should have had the SAME border and padding and thus the SAME height. Unless CHROME has an important rule overriding the padding on certain input types; which would be annoying.

Comment: @JackWilliams: As for why it doesn't work in your example, WebKit's default stylesheet actually uses `box-sizing: border-box` on `input[type="submit"]` elements, but `box-sizing: content-box` on `input[type="text"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The default stylesheet in WebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css?rev=160627#L662) (and probably other browsers) is to blame:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    color: ButtonText;
    padding: 2px 6px 3px 6px;
    border: 2px outset ButtonFace;
    background-color: ButtonFace;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

See that `box-sizing: border-box`? That's making your button's height behave intuitively (at least for me): the padding and borders "grow in" from your maximum height of `50px` instead of "growing out".

The default `box-sizing` property of all elements (and therefore your textbox) is `box-sizing: content-box`, which is computed differently.

To fix it, just make them both use the same box model (I'd go with `box-sizing: border-box;`). Better yet, save yourself some trouble and do it for *all* elements:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

There's even [a polyfill for IE7 and IE6](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill), if you support them.

Comment: "Do it for all" - You sire are a genius!

Answer (score 1):

use  box-sizing: content-box; in sample1 class

```
  .sample1 {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2em;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  .sample1 {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2em;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```